# Using dash (-) as part of key name in parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am creating a azure pipeline job and wanted to use `all-features` name as key parameter. It is valid in yaml but looks like I can't use this in condition or somehow azure parse it wrong. It is possible to make it work?

```yaml
parameters:
  all-features: false
  name: cargo_check

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.name }}
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-16.04
  variables:
    cliflags: ''
  steps:
  - template: ../steps/install-rust.yml
    parameters:
      rustup_toolchain: ${{ parameters.rust }}

  - script: echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=cliflags]$(cliflags) --all-features'
    enabled: ${{ parameters.all-features }}  ###### at this line I am getting error #######
    displayName: "Activate all available features"
```

Error:

> /ci/jobs/cargo-check.yml@templates (Line: 99, Col: 14): **Unexpected symbol: 'all-features'. Located at position 12 within expression: parameters.all-features.** For more help, refer to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=842996
>
> /ci/jobs/cargo-check.yml@templates (Line: 99, Col: 14): **Unexpected value '${{ parameters.all-features }}'**

*Workaround would be change name from `paramters.all-features` to `parameters.all_features` but I would love to use dash(-). It will be the same parameter name as in command line interface what is my point in this case.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Short answer:

You can use `parameters['all-features']` instead of `parameters.all-features` and it will work.

---

## Long answer:

> Using dash(-) as part of key name in paramters (Azure pipelines)

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is by designed. After a period of investigation, but could not found any workaround to solve this issue.

Just as the document [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops) stats:

> **Variables** As part of an expression, you may access variables using one of two syntaxes:
>
> - Index syntax: variables['MyVar']
> - Property dereference syntax: variables.MyVar
>
> **In order to use property dereference syntax, the property name must**:
>
> - **Start with a-Z or _**
> - **Be followed by a-Z 0-9 or _**

Hope this help you.

Comment: It look like `varibales['My-Var']['My-SecondVar']` is incorrect?